# nftables rule: No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter, nftables

I am trying to apply below nftables rule which I adopted from this [guide](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_packet_header_fields#Matching_TCP.2FUDP.2FUDPlite_traffic):

```
nft add rule filter INPUT tcp flags != syn counter drop
```

somehow this is ending up with:

> Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

Can anyone spot what exactly I might be missing in this rule?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably missing your table or chain.

```
nft list ruleset
```

will give you what you are working with. If it prints out nothing, you're missing both.

```
nft add table ip filter # create table
nft add chain ip filter INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0 \; } # create chain
```

Then you should be able to add your rule to the chain.

NOTE: If you're logged in with ssh, your connection will be suspended.

Comment: When I ran the `INPUT` one, I got `zsh: parse error near \`}'`. This can be fxed by adding another backslash in front of the closing curly bracket. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting `Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory` for nftables counter rules on an embedded Linux system built with Yocto.

In my case, the issue was due to kernel configuration. I had to enable the following:

- `CONFIG_NFT_COUNTER=m` so that I could create counters.
- `CONFIG_NFT_OBJREF=m` so that I could refer to the counters by name in rules.

This mailing list post helped me:

[[OpenWrt-Devel] nftables: named counters broken on 18.06.4](https://desiato.infradead.org/pipermail/openwrt-devel/2019-September/024588.html) — September 2019

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET=y`.

https://zigford.org/firewalld-kernel-requirements.html was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message, my fault however was, that I didn't write INPUT in capital letters.

Wrong:

```
nft add rule filter input tcp flags != syn counter drop
```

Correct:

```
nft add rule filter INPUT tcp flags != syn counter drop
```