# nftables refuses to add rules "Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory"

Tags: filter, nftables

**Problem:**

When trying to add nft rules, I keep getting "Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory"

**Example command:**

`nft add rule netdev filter input ip daddr 10.10.10.10 counter`

**Troubleshooting:**

- Confirmed "netdev filter" is as listed table with `nft list tables`
- Make sure nftables.service was running.
- The unit file shows /etc/nftables.conf is being used.
- Running all commands as root.
- [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537912/nftables-rule-no-such-file-or-directory-error) recommends setting `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET=y`. How and were do I do this? Its not clear.

**System**

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Kernel 5.4.0-91-generic

Not sure else how to troubleshoot this, the error is very vague. What am I missing? Why can I not add nft rules?

Answer (score 1):

The `netdev` address family does not have an `input` hook, but an `ingress` hook.
Your command might still be valid, but only if you had created a base chain named `input` first, by e.g.

```
nft add chain netdev filter input \{ type filter hook ingress device "eth0" priority filter; policy accept; \}
```

Here, the first `filter` is the *name* of the pre-existing `netdev filter` table. The second `filter` specifies the *type* of the chain, and the third `filter` is the standard name for the normal *priority* for filter chains.

The recommendation to set `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET=y` would probably also mean using the `inet` address family instead of `netdev` unless you have specific need to use the latter.

Comment: Note that this command will actually fail as is because the `detdev` address family requires a device specification in addition to the usual stuff, so if the network device is named `eth0`, the command would be `nft add chain netdev filter input '{ type filter hook ingress device "eth0" priority filter; policy accept; }'`. You can determine the actual device name using `ip link show`.